# VSTS View of build status by branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'd like to create a report which is the build status of each of our builds by branch for all the current branches in my Git repository - much like on the right hand side of the the summary page but spanning all build definitions. I'm happy to use the API and create the report myself but I can't seem to find any way to filter the information by branch in the API. Here's the sort of query I want to perform:

> https://(instance).visualstudio.com/(Project)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=(definitionID)&sourceBranch=(BranchID)

but sourceBranch doesn't seem to be a valid parameter

Comment: Are you succeed getting builds by branch name with my solution?

Comment: Yep, that's fantastic. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify branchName (replace / to %2F). For example (Dev-v1 branch):

```
https://XXX.visualstudio.com/[team project name]/_apis/build/Builds?branchName=refs%2Fheads%2FDev-v1&definitions=17
```

Comment: I'd like to display this badge on my github repo, but this url only works if you are currently logged in with vsts. Is there a way to authenticate with vsts using a token in the url or equivalent?

Comment: @tura08 No, there isn't. You can build a app (e.g. web api) to cal VSTS REST API, then you can use that web api directly.

Comment: Fair enough, another option is to run a script at the end of the build that uploads the svg from this api to a blob store like S3, then reference that directly in the readme.